# ansible uri and body format

Tags: web-services, ansible, uri

Here are my body's model

```
{
  "specs": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "id": "7dcf2db8-858e-4c00-bbde-e0c5c734770c"
    }
  ]
}
```

trying to convert this last for uri module

```
   body_format: json
   body:
    specs:
      id: "id"
      name: "name"
```

how to convert this last correctly ? switch to raw ?

Comment: Since YAML is a superset of JSON, you can literally just paste your JSON after the `body:` and voila (just ensure it's still indented correctly); so, `body: {"specs": [` ... and so forth. That said, your YAML is missing the leading `- ` in front of `id:` that would make `specs:` into a list

Comment: Hi WC to SO! this is more of a simple conversion question. you can use https://www.json2yaml.com/ for conversion into yaml in future in case needed as I like the representation of yaml better

Answer (score 3):

`specs` is an array of dicts so the right syntax is:

```
body_format: json
body:
  specs:
    - id: "id"
      name: "name"
```